# Auto update the nuspec file during the build process

Tags: tfs, nuget, build-automation, nuget-package, nuspec

I have been able to use [NuGetter](http://nugetter.codeplex.com/) to create a build definition to automate the NuGet package creation process and to upload the package to the NuGet repository.

But, I would like to automate the process even further. The following is a list of steps I would like to automate as part of the build process:

- The build process should be able to build the nuspec file, instead of me manually creating this file and saving it in the source control repository for the build process to pick it up.
- The build process should be able to replace the nuspec fields.

The nuspec fields that I really want to be able to automate are:

**Authors**
   I would like the build process to replace this field in the nuspec file with the name of the person who is check-in the code.

**releaseNotes**
   I would like the build process to replace this field in the nuspec file with the check-in comment.

Has anyone been able to accomplish this? If so, how did you go about automating it?

Answer (score 4):

This may help.

I created an automated process to publish updates for an open source project.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/NugetAutomation

Some things of interest to you are possibly.

- How we use powershell to copy a 'template' nuspec and inject the fields we need. (you can use this to similarly replace the 'authors, releaseNotes' fields)
- Ping the public nuget server to get the current version and increase the version.

It requires some Powershell knowledge, but I hope it gives you a start.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your script

Answer (score 0):

this post here [How to avoid xml document generation when using nuget pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547853/how-to-avoid-xml-document-generation-when-using-nuget-pack) has some ideas

```
<XmlUpdate Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd" XmlFileName="My.Assembly.nuspec" XPath="//package/metadata/licenseUrl" Value="http://someurl" />          
<XmlUpdate Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd" XmlFileName="My.Assembly.nuspec" XPath="//package/metadata/projectUrl" Value="http://someurl" />          
<XmlUpdate Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd" XmlFileName="My.Assembly.nuspec" XPath="//package/metadata/iconUrl" Value="http://somenice.png" />            
<XmlUpdate Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd" XmlFileName="My.Assembly.nuspec" XPath="//package/metadata/tags" Value="My.Assembly" />           
<XmlUpdate Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd" XmlFileName="My.Assembly.nuspec" XPath="//package/metadata/releaseNotes" Value="Review readme.txt for details." />
```

Comment: This post does not answer my question. I am able to create the NuGet package, with correct content files, during the build process using PowerShell scripts, which works perfectly. I am not trying to include/exclude file from the NuGet package. My issue is that, I would like to generate the nuspec file during the build process. So, I would like to first check-out the nupsec file, second update the nuspec file fields for Author and releaseNotes, third check-in the nuspec file. These three steps should happen before NuGetter retrieves the nuspec file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new post build event that trigger a script that's taking the version from the "packages.config" file and write them back to the nuspec file.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command .'$(ProjectDir)..\PathToScirptLocation\NuspecAutoUpdate.ps1' -NuspecPath '$(ProjectDir)API.nuspec' -PackagesConfigPath '$(ProjectDir)packages.config'
```

I upload the script and the post build event to my GIT for anyone who will need it.

https://github.com/avrum/NuspecAutoUpdate